# "Invalid Request" while trying to get eBay user Access Token. No specific error number given

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, token, ebay-api

This is the extremely vague response I'm getting, while trying to get a user access token:

```
{
"error":"invalid_request",
"error_description":"request is invalid",
"error_uri":null
}
```

Here is my code:

```
$headers = array (
        "Authorization: ".sprintf(
                     'Basic %s',
                     base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $client_id, $client_secret))
                 )." ",
        'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

);

$apiURL = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
$urlParams = array (
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" => $auth_code,
        "redirect_uri" => "xxx-xxx-xxx-SBX-ccd-xxx"
);
$data_json = json_encode($urlParams);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json );

$resp = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

print_r ( $resp );
```

How can I debug this when it doesn't even hint at what's wrong with my request?
I've been through this page step-by-step:
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-user-token.html#Updating

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you encode your body in Json while the authorization server expects body parameters in POST field format.
The headers should also contains key/value pairs but you are sending only a list of values

Could you please try with the following code:

```
$headers = array (
        'Authorization' => sprintf('Basic %s',base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $client_id, $client_secret))),
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);

$apiURL = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
$urlParams = array (
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" => $auth_code,
        "redirect_uri" => "xxx-xxx-xxx-SBX-ccd-xxx"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Should be removed on production
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $urlParams );

$resp = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

print_r ( $resp );
```

Comment: Hi Florent, Thank you for your response. I tried it. It doesn't work either even if I do not encode it. The same error happened.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. I think the problem comes from the header that should be an associative array

Answer (score 0):

*Authorization* header should have a following format:

```
'Authorization' => sprintf('Basic <%s>',base64_encode(sprintf('%s:%s', $client_id, $client_secret)))
```